# How to implement Datetime picker for bootstrap 5 UI

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, datetimepicker

Not able to find any solution to implement datetime picker for Bootstrap 5 (front end uses Bootstrap 5.1.0).

I found one solution, but it's for Bootstrap 3. It does not work for Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as an example if you want. I think all you're asking for is not really pertaining to *Bootstrap* and more of a simple *HTML* question. I think all you're interested in is the knowledge that you can put `type="date"` on an input element and it will allow you to click on it and become a "date/time picker."

However, you can certainly style it with Bootstrap classes, like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Pick a date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" style="width:auto" />
</div>
```